# jquery ui resizable div with scroll , the handle is moving when scrolling

Tags: css, jquery-ui, overflow, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a problem getting the south handle to be stuck to the bottom when scrolling a resizable div , 
am using jquery ui resizable function to set a custom div as a handle, the resize functionality is working, but when i use the scrollbar the handle moves with the content, i want it to remain at the bottom of the div :

[image]

here is the html :

```
<div class="Container">
  <h2>Title</h2>

  <div class="Content">
   a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...
  a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...
  a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...
  a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...
  a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...
  a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...
  a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...
  a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...
  a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...a long text...

       <div id="handle" class = "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the jquery call to resize :

```
$(".Content").resizable({ handles: "s" });
```

and the css :

```
.Container
{
  width:250px; 
  padding:3px; 
  background:#f00;
}
.Content
{
    position : relative;
  height:224px;
   overflow:auto;
    background:#fff;
}

#handle {
    height : 8px;
    background : #00aa00;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/2389/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should wrap your `long text` in a div and give `overflow` to that div

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/ftkbL/2392/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="Content">
 <div class="text">blah... ..blah</div>
 <div id="handle" class = "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Content
{
background:#fff;
height:224px;    
}

.text
{
position : relative;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add height: -webkit-calc(100% - 5px); calc(100% - 5px); on that .text div. So your handle won't overrun your scrollbar.